# What are some better alternatives to HIV antibody test?

Tags: weight-loss, hiv, loss-of-appetite, tonsillitis, antibodies

I've been having HIV symptoms  for more than 4-5 months, I reran  the antibody test for five times it all became negative, the doctor said that you didn't have to worry about HIV anymore as all the testing results became negative,  But  I still have Some symptoms of HIV which are

1. Swollen  tonsils (lasting for more than a month)
2. Sudden weight loss (4-5kg)
3. Muscle and joint pain
4. Loss of appetite

What are some other possible cause of these symptoms other than HIV

Comment: Items 2 through 4 are symptoms of hundreds of things. Only #1 is unusual and specific. And those things really aren't unique to AIDS (the disease caused by HIV), so there's no reason for repeated tests. You don't have AIDS.